# Use Ramda indexBy with variable index

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I need to transform some JSON data, and Ramda's indexBy does just about exactly what I want.  The code below works for a single object:

```
const operativeIndex = R.pipe(R.head, R.keysIn,
   R.intersection(['Weight', 'Height', 'Month', 'Week']), R.head);
const reIndex = R.indexBy(R.prop(operativeIndex(testObject)), testObject);
```

But to map an array of objects through my re-indexing function, I believe I need to rewrite `reIndex` so that it needs only a single injection of `testObject`.

How can I do that?

---

To help visualize the task: the current code transforms `testObject` from an array like this, which will have one of the 4 allowed indices:

```
[{ Height: '45',
      L: '-0.3521',
      M: '2.441',
      S: '0.09182'},
{ Height: '45.5',
      L: '-0.3521',
      M: '2.5244',
      S: '0.09153'}]
```

into an object like this:

```
{ '45': 
   { Height: '45',
     L: '-0.3521',
     M: '2.441',
     S: '0.09182' },
  '45.5': 
   { Height: '45.5',
     L: '-0.3521',
     M: '2.5244',
     S: '0.09153' } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want `reIndex` to be a function that takes a list of objects and produces an object index.

If yes you could do it this way

```
const operativeIndex = R.pipe(
  R.keysIn,
  R.intersection(['Weight', 'Height', 'Month', 'Week']),
  R.head
)

const reIndex = R.indexBy(R.chain(R.prop, operativeIndex))
```

Then you could do `reIndex(list)` [Demo](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7B%20Height%3A%20%2745%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20L%3A%20%27-0.3521%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20M%3A%20%272.441%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20S%3A%20%270.09182%27%7D%2C%0A%7B%20Height%3A%20%2745.5%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20L%3A%20%27-0.3521%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20M%3A%20%272.5244%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20S%3A%20%270.09153%27%7D%5D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20operativeIndex%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20R.keysIn%2C%0A%20%20R.intersection%28%5B%27Weight%27%2C%20%27Height%27%2C%20%27Month%27%2C%20%27Week%27%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20R.head%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20reIndex%20%3D%20R.indexBy%28R.chain%28R.prop%2C%20operativeIndex%29%29%0A%0AreIndex%28data%29%0A).

BTW keep in mind that `keysIn` goes up the prototype chain and the order is **NOT** guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed.  With your rewriting of `reIndex`, I can now use `R.map(reIndex, list)` and use a single function to re-index many objects like the `testObject` above.